# jscrollpane vertical scroll bar

Tags: javascript, jscrollpane

is it possible to turn off the vertical scroll bar in jscrollpane?  Also is there a list of variables you can use/set?

```
$(function()
{
    var api = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane({showArrows:false}).data('jsp');
    $('#scroll-up').bind(
        'click',
        function()
        {
            api.scrollByY(-10);
            return false;
        }
    );
    $('#scroll-down').bind(
        'click',
        function()
        {
            api.scrollByY(10);
            return false;
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove these piece of code from jquery.jscrollpane.css:

```
.jspVerticalBar
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 16px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: it's working but how to remove the space found on left that represent jspVerticalBar place on left